# How to get the part of a string before a specific string in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a Picklist string like this:

`Graphic Design-Free Trial; Graphic Design-Subscription`

I wish to get the Graphic Design bit before "-Free Trial"

Note that it could also be like this:

`Graphic Design-Subscription; Graphic Design-Free Trial`

How would I go about it?

I believe `substringBetween(open, close)` is going to help perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

> I wish to get the Graphic Design bit before "-Free Trial"

For this you can use [`String.substringBefore()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substringBefore) method:

```
String picklistValues = 'Graphic Design-Free Trial; Graphic Design-Subscription';
String beforeFreeTrial = picklistValues.substringBefore('-Free Trial');
```

And then `beforeFreeTrial` will be just *Graphic Design*.

If your string would be *Graphic Design-Subscription; Graphic Design-Free Trial*, then you would get *Graphic Design-Subscription; Graphic Design* back

Comment: Thanks mate, I settled with substringBetween(open, close).